# Xcode compilation failure for wxDVC renderer

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, renderer

ALL,

```
#ifdef __WXOSX__
#include "wx/toplevel.h"
#include "wx/font.h"
#include "wx/settings.h"
#include "wx/utils.h"
#include "wx/osx/private.h"
#include "wx/osx/private/available.h"
#include "wx/osx/cocoa/dataview.h"
#include "wx/renderer.h"
#include "wx/stopwatch.h"
#include "wx/dcgraph.h"
#endif

class SortColumnRenderer
    : public wxDataViewRenderer
{
public:
    explicit SortColumnRenderer(
        wxCheckBoxState state = wxCHK_CHECKED,
        wxDataViewCellMode mode = wxDATAVIEW_CELL_ACTIVATABLE,
        int align = wxDVR_DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT)
    : wxDataViewRenderer( GetDefaultType(), mode, mode ), m_checkedState(state)
    {
        m_allow3rdStateForUser = false;
        m_value = "Ascending";
        NSButtonCell* cell;
        cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
        [cell setAlignment:ConvertToNativeHorizontalTextAlignment(GetAlignment())];
        [cell setButtonType: NSSwitchButton];
        [cell setImagePosition:NSImageLeft];
        [cell setAllowsMixedState:YES];
        SetNativeData(new wxDataViewRendererNativeData( cell ) );
        [cell release];
    };
};
```

The code above produces a lot of errors, such as:

```
Expected unqualified-id NSObjCRuntime.h
```

that comes from the #include "wx/osx/cocoa/dataview.h".

And if I comment out that include I get:

```
Unknown type name 'NSButtonCell'; did you mean 'NSButton'?
```

Trying to import AppKit/NSButtonCell.h, result in the same set of errors as above: `Expected unqualified-id...`.

I am trying to mimic the code from the wxCheckIconTextRenderer, but without the Icon portion.

Anybody have an idea?

TIA!

Comment: Are you compiling Obj-C code as C++ by chance?

Comment: Vadim, I think I am. Because I put this code inside the C++ source. And I shouldn't do that, right? Any suggestions on how to avoid that? Or maybe how to use wxCheckIconTextRenderer without the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the code using Objective-C as such, i.e. put it in a file with `.mm` extension if you don't want to explicitly use `-x` compiler option.